# Different Types of Continuity in Reflexive Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space with dual $X^*$. 
Let $K\subset X$ be a nonempty closed convex set.
The mapping $F: K\rightarrow X^*$ is said to be:

- **weakly continuous** if $F$ is continuous w.r.t. the weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$
  and the induced topology on $K$;
- **continuous on finite dimensional subspaces** if for any subspaces
  $M\subset X$ the restriction of F to $K\cap M$ is continuous w.r.t the 
  weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$ and the induced topology on $K\cap M$;
- **hemicontinuous** if for any $x, y\in K$ the restriction of $F$ to $[x, y]$
  is continuous w.r.t the weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$ and the induced topology on $[x, y]$.

We are easy to verify that

**weak continuity** $\Rightarrow$ **continuity on finite dimensional subspaces**

**continuity on finite dimensional subspaces** $\Rightarrow$ **hemicontinuity**.

The reverse is not true in general.

I am stuck in constructing counterexamples for the reverse implication.

Thank you for all comments and helping.

Comment: The topology is induced from what topology? Is it the strong one? Also, in the second type of continuity, are assuming that $M$ is a proper subspace?

Comment: The topology is induced from topology generated by norm on $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I. Conterexample: continuity on finite dimensional subspaces **doesn't imply** weak continuity

Let $X = \ell_2$ (or any other infinite dimensional reflexive Banach space) and $K$ be the closed unit ball of $X$. Let $u$ be an arbitrary non-zero vector in $X^*$.

Let $e_{\alpha}$ be a Hamel basis in $X$ with $\|e_{\alpha}\| = 1$. Fix an arbitrary unbounded sequence of real numbers $c_{\alpha}$. Define a map $F$ on vectors $e_{\alpha}$ by $F(e_{\alpha}) = c_{\alpha} u$. Now extend $F$ to $K$ by linearity. We get a map $F$ from $K$ to $X^*$. Since $F$ is linear, it is continuous on every bounded subspace of $X$. On the other hand, since the sequence $c_{\alpha}$ is unbounded, $F$ is unbounded on $K$ (and thus it is not continuous).

II. Conterexample: hemicontinuity **doesn't imply** continuity on finite dimensional subspaces

Let $X={\mathbb R}^2$, $K$ be the unit ball of $X$, and $u\in X^*\setminus \{0\}$. Define $F(x,y)$ as follows
$$F(x) = \cases {0,&if $x=0$;\\
\frac{x_1x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^{10}} \cdot u, &otherwise.}
$$

It's easy to check that $F$ is continuous on every segment $[x,y]$ but $F$ is not continuous at $0$ (e.g. consider the sequence $(1/k^5, 1/k)$ that tends to $0$ as $k\to\infty$ but $F(1/k^5, 1/k)\not\to 0$).

P.S. Note that since $X$ is reflexive, there is no difference between the weak-* topology and weak topology on $X^*$.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting constructions.

Comment: I would like to ask your comments in the following question math.stackexchange.com/questions/482684/… Thank you for your kind help